# Extracting the byte value of double from memory

Tags: c++, double, byte

I'm trying to extract the byte value of a double from the computer's memory.  The reason for this is accuracy, as the final value that is represented to the user has some rounding performed.

Ideally, I want to be able to extract the sign, exponent and mantissa from the number (IEEE 754 standard)

From what I understand, casting to an unsigned char is the way to go.  I have the following code snippet (stolen elsewhere), but I don't trust the results - there's no byte output for any integer values:

```
double d = 2;
unsigned char *p = (unsigned char*)&d;
```

Can anyone guide me in the right direction in order to extract byte representation of double numbers accurately, or give any advice/comments on how to proceed?

Comment: Are you aware of the [`frexp()`](http://cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/frexp/) function in the standard library?

Comment: Integer values? It's a `double`. And how are you arranging for output to appear? That code just creates a `double` and a pointer.

Comment: Also, I don't understand your premise.  How is extracting the raw bits going to help you with accuracy?

Comment: I think this is a good exercise, for you to understand the layout of a `double` in memory, and also for you to work with casting, masking, and bit-shifting to truly understand what's going on "under the hood."

Comment: What do you mean with "there's no byte output for any integer values"? Show us your output. And btw. why use c-style cast instead of c++-style?

Comment: Briefly (and this is from my understanding) floating point binary values cannot, sometimes, represent numbers accurately.  So, some potential loss/rounding is involved. If I'm performing simulation or some number crunching that requires accuracy and several sessions/machines to be used, if I save intermittent results as ASCII values, potentially, when I start a new session using said results, I'll have an inaccuracy that will become bigger and bigger as time goes on (even if in reality it'll be small).

Comment: Plus, the above snippet is not my work - I stole it from the web.  The output in that particular example is nothing.  Nothing gets printed (std::cout, perhaps this is the reason?)

Comment: @johnnyturbo3: Again how are you trying to print that? Note that for a `char c` `std::cout<<c` will print the ascii value of `c` and not a number representing that value and for your `p` `std::cout<<p` will interpret `p` as a nullterminated charactersequence, so it will stop printing when it encounters the first char with value 0

Comment: Maybe the goal is to write the binary representation to disk, or something like that, with the aim of being able to perfectly read it in again later? If so, that raises another question: Is there a 1-to-1 mapping between doubles and the text that comes from `printf("%f")` (or `printf("%g")` or `cout <<`) ?

Comment: @johnnyturbo3, you should edit your question to include something like "my goal is to store intermittent results (which are in a double) to disk in such as way that I can later reread from disk into the double".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're doing it right. You can treat `p` as an array `unsigned char[sizeof(double)]` now.

For example:

```
for (int i = 0; i != sizeof(double); ++i)  printf("%02X ", p[i]);
```

For `d = 0.125` this prints `00 00 00 00 00 00 C0 3F`. Reversing endianness and decomposing into parts, this is:

```
00111111 11000000 0 0 0 0 0 0
   3F       C0    0 0 0 0 0 0

0   01111111100   0...<52 times>...0
S     Exponent         Mantissa
+     1023 - 3           1.0
```

The exponent field's value is 1020, which gives an exponent of −3 after correcting by the bias of 1023, and the mantissa is 1.0, after including the implicit leading 1. So the value is 2<sup>−3</sup> = 1/8.

Answer (score 3):

If your motivation is only accuracy, use `printf("%a\n", d);`

It displays the same information as going to the binary representation would, but it displays it in a format that's almost human-readable. Here (that is, for `d=2;`), it displays `0x1p+1`. The number after `0x` is the mantissa, normalized between 1 and 2, and in hexadecimal. The number after `p` is the exponent. It is displayed in decimal but it represents a power of two.